# Is there way to set detailRowHeight prop to 100% in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Recently started working on a master detail structure angular ag-grid. The structure has two levels of master-detail nesting. I need to fix the heights of inner - 2 grids such that they occupy all available real estate on the screen. Currently, ag-grid defaults it to 300 px and a lot of whitespace or unused space appears on a 1920x1200 screen resolution monitor. I also need to have fixed headers for all grids.

Any ideas or pointers would be appreciated...

**Update**: Referring to a forked version of plunker example from ag-grid here - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/yUzo4EqONEmgCmIw This is simple and basic set up for master-detail grid.

*Note that*: I haven't set any detail row height and have setup just one record to show up in the grid to test for the issue.

If you run the plunker code and view the result in separate window, notice that the inner / child grid doesn't occupy all the space available below it. In other words, it doesn't take as much as space/height available from parent container (master's detail row). The default 300px master detailRowHeight is making height fixed for inner grid. Also, from documentation, detailRowHeight prop doesn't seem to take something similar as 100% or 100vh and only takes fixed pixels number. Added a picture of the example below and the height / unused space I referred

[image]

We have different resolutions that users use to view data in grid and the heights of inner grids need to auto-adjust taking max. available space to show most information in the grids.

Comment: Probably not going to get traction on this - not to SO post rules. You need to provide code and a more specific problem. You threw out a few things only described, no code - I work in ag-grid all the time and can probably help you but not with this little info...

Comment: thanks for checking. I've added some more details and basic code example, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, I pulled it from the documentation:

In your component.ts file add this method. If it's a detail row it will apply different calculations than the other rows.

```
  public rowHeight(params) {
        if (params.node && params.node.detail) {
            var offset = 80;
            var allDetailRowHeight = params.data.callRecords.length * 28;
            return allDetailRowHeight + offset;
        } else {
            // otherwise return fixed master row height
            return 25;
        }
    };
```

In your template add the following: `[getRowHeight]="rowHeight"`

```
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  id="myGrid"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [masterDetail]="true"
  [detailCellRendererParams]="detailCellRendererParams"
  [getRowHeight]="rowHeight"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

Hopefully this will get you moving forward. Good Luck!

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#detail-row-height

Comment: yeah, did this too. But, was unable to have fixed headers for the grid. The inner grid should expand until it reaches the max. remaining height in the screen. This function will get you full calculated/dynamic height of the detail row and the page may become a long scroll.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have a great, full solution for you but as a starting point I would use CSS to override the styles ag-grid is setting - I don't think detailRowHeight is going to help.

Here's my plunk getting close to what you want with some simple CSS I put in index.html. You can use !important to override ag-grid styles, or you could use javascript to set the CSS after ag-grid does. I prefer !important in this case and don't have to worry about timing.
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/mmXBBJE5Wa1JrX7v

The problem I wasn't going to get into is getting it to dynamically fill up available space, depending on the row selected, scroll position, etc. I can't think of any simple way to achieve that - I do this type of thing in grid often and end up writing javascript to calculate the available space, and then set the CSS in javascript.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did play around the css for a fix - something like -           
 `:host >>> div[ref="eFullWidthContainer"] {
  height: 100% !important;
}

:host >>> div[row-id^="detail"] {
  height: 98.5% !important;
} `                                                                                                                        
  This works good for one row, but when you have several rows / records to show it gets very messy. You can change the data in the plunker & notice the expanded rows then in separate window. The grid is messed up and headers don't show up. :(

Comment: Yep, that is what I was talking about with selected row, scroll position, etc. - I don't have any way to handle that other than using DOM selectors and clientHeight on the elements to calculate available space for yourself in your code - and set the CSS appropriately per my example or the selectors you've been using. height: calc(100% - 40px) I think will work better than 98.5%, I'm just cutting out the padding exactly with calc().

Answer (score 0):

In ag-grid you have the possibility to set auto height for details.

> Set grid property detailRowAutoHeight=true to have the detail grid to dynamically change it's height to fit it's rows.

```
const gridOptions = {
// dynamically set row height for all detail grids
detailRowAutoHeight: true,

// other grid options ...
```

}

However if you are providing your own detail component...
detailCellRenderer: 'MyOwnDetailsComponent',
then, it might not work and you will still need to provide an grid options height detail content through...
detailRowHeight: 560,

Please see the ag-grid documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/master-detail-height/#auto-height)